# How to scroll to bottom after an element appears (using react-slidedown)

Tags: javascript, reactjs

A bit of a newbie question I'm sure, but I can't figure it out.

I have an optin form that I reveal upon clicking on a link. The reveal is done using [react-slidedown](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-slidedown).

The problem I have is that if this is on the bottom of the page, the form that slides down is not seen - you have to scroll down to see it. How can I scroll automatically to the bottom of the page after the form slides down?

[Here is the codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-slidedown-demo-ziga-8nmcc?file=/main.js) (scroll to the bottom for the link)

I've been dealing with this for the past two hours, but haven't managed to make it work.

(Note: I'm pretty new at react.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the following to your function "handleToggle":

```
  setTimeout(() => {
    window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);
  }, 100);
```

since the update of the state and rendering takes some time, we delay our `scrollTo` function by 100ms

It should give you the effect that you're looking for... forked [codesandbox here](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-slidedown-demo-ziga-iwb9x?file=/main.js)